# Is there a way to use fully qualified sql column names in ado .net?

Tags: sql, sql-server, .net-core, ado.net

I am working on connecting a database (around 30 tables) with my .net Web API.
Right now I use the following code:

```
public static int GetIntNullCheck(IDataRecord reader, string columnName, int valueIfNull = -1)
{
    if (reader == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(reader));
    int ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal(columnName);
    return reader.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? valueIfNull : reader.GetInt32(ordinal);
}
```

Because some of my queries join many tables, I want to use fully qualified column names to access the results.
Is there a way to do this in a clean way in ado.net? There are multiple answered questions on this topic on the internet but every solution is a hack or not practical in my case.

***Things I thought about but do not want to use:***

**1. Use SQL column aliases for conflicting column names**

This would be theoretically possible but my queries are already very large and it would not be practical to do that for 20+ columns per query

**2. Alter the database to have unique column names across the whole database**

This is possibly the most realistic solution but the column names become very cluttered. If I have no other option I have to do this but I would really like to avoid it.

**3. Use `SQLDataReader.GetSchemaTable()` to write this functionality myself**

Firstly  I don't like this because it feels like a hack and is probably bad for performance. Additionally this would not work with table aliases but I have to use those on some of my queries for self joins. Nevertheless I tried to implement it but I only get null values on the `BaseTableName` field of the table although I use `command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo))`

**3. Use a different database connection library**

Ado.Net is widely used and I use mostly libraries which are used by many people because they are easier to maintain - If I have a problem with them almost certainly 100 other people on the internet had the same issue and there are blogposts discussing the solutions. I would swith the library though if there is no clean way in ado.net.

There has to be a good way to do this. Like I mentioned there are many people having this question and ado.net is big enough so it shoul support it. I just want to be able to use `reader.GetOrdinal(tableName + "." + columnName);`. I always used it with the JDBC in java so it has to be possible from the SQL-side

Therefore here my resulting question:

**Did I miss some possible solution or do you think one of my described solutions is better than I thought?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr; Usa aliases. That's what they are there for.**

> Is there a way to use fully qualified sql column names in ado .net?

No. The resultset gets it's column names based on the last part of the identifier, even if you're using a multi-part identifier - I'm pretty sure it's not an ADO.Net thing, because it also happens in SSMS (or any other database client I know of).

If you run the following query on any SQL Server database you'll see it yourself:

```
SELECT c.Name
     , c.Name As [Column Name]
     , T.Name
     , T.Name As [Table Name]
FROM sys.Tables As T
JOIN sys.Columns As C 
    ON C.object_id = T.object_id
```

The column names you get back are these:

```
Name    Column Name     Name    Table Name
```

> **Things I thought about but do not want to use:**

> 1. Use SQL column aliases for conflicting column names

That's actually the best solution to this problem as it's the easiest to implement and maintain.
You don't have to alias *all the columns of every query*, only the columns that cause the conflict. Usually, it's not that many.

> 2. Alter the database to have unique column names across the whole database

That's might might seem like an acceptable idea, but it can become quite cumbersome very quickly.
I once designed a database that had all the columns prefixed with their containing table's name.
It's easy when you have tables such as `Users`, `Orders` or `Products`, and it even kinda makes sense - when you see `Order_Id` in the query you know exactly what table it's coming from and you (at least in theory) never need to alias anything - **However** - The database I was working on had some really long-named tables - tables with 4, 5 and 6 words in their names - So I've started to use abbreviations - and then you get things like `PMTM_Something_Id` and oops - there's goes the readability out the window - and if you're using the entire table name it's even worst - and I'm not even talking about bridge tables for many-to-many relationships.
I'm not going to do that mistake again.

> 3. Use SQLDataReader.GetSchemaTable() to write this functionality myself

Don't go there. Really, don't. You're only going to get yourself into an even bigger mess than what you have now.

> 4. Use a different database connection library

As I wrote at the beginning - it's not an ADO.Net thing - it's an SQL thing - so using a different database connection library will not solve this.
I'm not sure how JDBC works, but it's fairly reasonable to assume `reader.GetOrdinal(tableName + "." + columnName);` simply does exactly what `reader.GetOrdinal(columnName);` does. It would be interesting to check that, however the last time I wrote anything in Java was literally in the previous millennium - so I'm not even going to try.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of agree with Zohar regarding column aliases.

Depending on how your queries are written, and your level of comfort in the coding language, it might be feasible to write a relatively simple utility (in say, c#) which can take as input, your original sql query, automatically add the required column aliases, and output it in another window ?

Then your code could just use the query with the required column aliases.

Comment: It might not be as easy as you might think. Sure, take anything beteen `select` and `from`. What about subqueries? Common table expressions? Order by clauses? Parsing sql isn't as simple as it seems at first glance.